# compare an array drawable to an array string android studio

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-studio, android-drawable

I want to compare my value of the spinner with the drawable picture and set the text visible how do I go about getting the object of a drawable in the array for comparison I tried the code below but no luck.

if (mSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("husky") &&
 mImageView.equals(r.nextInt(R.drawable.husky_2317)) {

mTextView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

```
public class Identify_Breed extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner mDogs;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Button mButton;
    private Random r;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private TextView mTextView2;

    //image arrays
    final Integer[] images = {R.drawable.husky_2317, R.drawable.kuvasz_852, R.drawable.papillon_2579,
            R.drawable.vizsla_2681,};

    final String[]  dogs= {"Select Item", "husky", "kuvasz", "papillon", "vizsla"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_identify__breed);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mDogs= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

       // final View root=mDogs.getRootView();
        ArrayAdapter <String> ad1= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, dogs);

        mDogs.setAdapter(ad1);

        mDogs.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                if (mDogs.getSelectedItem().equals("husky") && 
mImageView.equals(r.nextInt(R.drawable.husky_2317)){
                    mTextView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (mDogs.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("husky") && (mImageView.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.husky_2317)).getConstantState())))
```

Comment: So i added your code and the last .getConstantState() is a error. when i removed the .getConstantState() it was fine but i tried that and the app stopped working when i use the image "husky_2317" with the spinner value "husky"

Comment: (mImageView.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.husky_2317).getConstantState())) this works fine but my app still crashs when i click husky on my spinner

Comment: null object reference ... you are not grabbing the value you want. Can you send me the project I will take a look? Easier for me that way to debug.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZZQ3q-UT0FmR25PWU0kkPFKhEdBBdpx7?usp=sharing  heres link to the project